# Password validation are false. repeated_password is extra field

Tags: symfony

I'm actually stuck with repeated validator.

In the documentation I found this example:

```
$builder->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
    'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
    'required' => true,
    'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
    'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
]);
```

> Upon a successful form submit, the value entered into both of the
> “password” fields becomes the data of the password key.

**both of the “password”** but where is the second fieldname?

I found in the sources of *RepeatedType*:

```
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'repeated';
}
```

But I send any variants of 'repeated_password', 'repeatedPassword' it doesn't work for me.

For more I get an error validation: "This form should not contain extra fields."
Ok let's add:

```
 ->add('repeated_password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
```

//

```
$form->isValid() //false
```

Validation **false**. No errors. Nothing.

I tried to define **first_name** and **second_name** properties, but this both goes to "This form should not contain extra fields."

How are you validate password === password_repeated?

Comment: If you take a look at the generated form, it's an array input. Given your example the fields would be called `example_form[password][first]` and `example_form[password][second]`.  Calling `handleRequest()` shoud take care of the validation for you. The issues you are having seem to be more related to client code than the form itself.

Answer (score 0):

The form element, you've mentioned, would render two fields - the first (password) and the second (repeat password). In order to render those fields, you have two options.

- Render all at once.

  {{ form_row(form.password) }}
- Render each password field individually.

  {{ form_row(form.password.first) }}
  {{ form_row(form.password.second) }}

Please check [the rendering section of the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#rendering) for more details.

Those fields would be validated automatically to check if password matches repeat password.
Please take a look at [the validation section of the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#validation) for more details.